# Sitecore Commerce with Salesforce

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine, commerce-catalog, salesforce-connect

I am looking to send Sitecore Commerce product data to Salesforce. Has anyone done something similar to that. There is FuseIT which can be used to send data to Salesforce but I am not sure if it can be work with Sitecore Commerce.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using minions in sitecore commerce, create minion block where we can get all the products from catalog and added them to the list and convert that list to json using serialization. Then call sales force post api in minion block. In minion configure you can set at what interval that minion should trigger and it will be posted to sales force periodically.

Comment: thanks for the reply. What about if I want to send product detail during checkout  phase. When a user buys a product and payment is completed then at the same time i want to send product detail with user information to salesforce. For that I can create a minion block?. Sorry I am very new to Sitecore commerce .

Comment: It can be achieved in two ways. 

1. Sitecore Helix side:When user gets redirected back to site from payment gateway, it will hit controller action. There using Order Provider you will get customer order, order will have product details. Then using these product detail you can triggere api to sales forces.

Comment: 2. Sitecore Commerce: When order gets created, IPendingOrdersMinionPipeline move order status from Pending to Release and then to Complete. You can create Plugin in commerce, this plugin will has your code block. You have patch that Block in configuresitecore.cs after "ReleaseOrderBlock". So when order gets create and order status is set to "Release", block will execute and trigger api to sales force.
**Please up vote if this information is helpfull

Comment: thanks alot. Is there any examples of creating a plugin in configuresitecore.cs. I am very new to sitecore commerce

Comment: in the product detail page lets say there is an interested in the product form which the user fills and submits. Can we add a siecore form there and add a custom save action to save user details in the core database and then use salesforce api to post the information to salesforce. For this , i need to create a minion as well?

Comment: No, dont have to create minion for your case. Create plugin in sitecore commerce solution. You will find sample sitecore commerce solution with plugin in sitecore commerce setup zip(inside Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.SDK.4.0.102.zip).

Comment: Comments are not for extended chat. Please update your answer with the above details and information, comments are often overlooked by users.